# What is the kind of encryption used in Zip 3.0?

Tags: encryption, zip

I am using zip on Arch and the version is given as "Zip 3.0 (July 5th 2008) by Info-Zip. Compiled with gcc 11.2.0 on Mar 22 2022. The encryption compilation information reads "[encryption, version 2.91 of 05 JAN 2007] (modified for Zip 3)"

What is the actual encryption algorithm used?

Answer (score 1):

Zip 3.0 uses the same encryption as the original [PKZIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKZIP), since it was meant to be able to produce compatible zip files. Files contained in the zip file are encrypted using a proprietary cipher informally known as ZipCrypto. Briefly, it's a symmetric cipher that uses three 32-bit keys derived from the password provided to `zip`. Somewhat ironically, probably the best academic description of it can be found in the research paper ["A Known-Plaintext Attack on the PKZIP Stream Cipher"](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-60590-8_12.pdf).

ZipCrypto has been considered [insecure](https://blog.devolutions.net/2020/08/why-you-should-never-use-zipcrypto/) for quite some time, and tools are available to break it with little effort. [Beta releases of Zip 3.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Info-ZIP#Official_betas) supporting AES-256 have been floating around since at least 2015.